# Convert array to tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

There is an array of data that needs to be converted to a tree:

```
const array = [{
  id: 5,
  name: 'vueJS',
  parentId: [3]
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'reactJS',
  parentId: [3]
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'js',
  parentId: [1]
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'development',
  parentId: null
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'oracle',
  parentId: [1,2]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'data-analysis',
  parentId: null
}];
```

Now it works using this function:

```
function arrayToTree(array, parent) {
  var unflattenArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.parentId === parent) {
      var children = arrayToTree(array, item.id);
      if(children.length) {
        item.children = children
      }
      unflattenArray.push(item)
    }
  });
  return unflattenArray;
}
console.log(arrayToTree(array, null));
```

I have two problems with this feature:

1. The value of "parentId" should be an array of id, for example -
   "parentId": [2, 3]
2. How to transfer to function only one argument - "array"?

https://codepen.io/pershay/pen/PgVJOO?editors=0010

Comment: Why would parentId have to be an array? Can you give an example of input in your question with the corresponding output that needs such multiple parents? For the second point: assign a default value to your parameter: `function arrayToTree(array, parent = null)`

Comment: How it can be a tree if node has several parents? Or is parentId are ids of all ancestors?

Comment: ....in your question.... Please ;-)

Comment: NB: a link to a "codepen" is not needed: you can create a snippet with the editor-toolbar that can be run within your question.

Comment: @trincot i'm updated question

Comment: So it is the input that has the multiple parents: in that case the title is misleading, because this no longer represents a tree, but a directed graph. What is the expected output?

Comment: Because when creating an object, parents are selected from the multi-select and fall into an array

Comment: It is not a tree (see subject). What is the expected output?

Comment: i'm updated codepen.

const tree - it is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I find this question confusing.  It sounds like what you are really saying is the array represents the “definition of node types in the tree” and not the actual instances of those nodes that will be in the tree.

So your problem is you need to copy the “definitions” from the array to new “instance” nodes in your tree.  This would let “Oracle” show twice, as you’d create a new “oracle instance” node for each parent in its parent array.   It wouldn’t technically need to be a deep copy depending on your use, so you could proof of concept with Object.assign, but each instance would point to the same parents array and that may or may not cause problems for that or future reference values you add to the definition.

Finally, depending on the size of the tree and what you are really trying to do, you might want to convert to a tree represented by nodes/edges instead of parent/children.  For really large datasets recursion can sometimes cause you problems.

Sorry I’m on my phone so some things are hard to see on the codepen.